# Angular 8 application is loading type="module" scripts instead of es5 on IE11

Tags: angular

I have a Angular 8 app. It does not load on IE11. When I checked `index.html` it turns out that it has only `type="module"` scripts included, and no es5:

```html
<script src="/runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="/polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="/styles.js" type="module"></script><script src="/vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="/main.js" type="module"></script></body>
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You should change TypeScript `target` to `es5`. This will generate two bundles each of es5 and es6. Also, angular will take care of which version to use on which browser.

You can set that in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"target": "es5"
```

Comment: @dragonfly, if this post solves your issue, please mark it as accepted.